# What are the effects of the different types of bombs?

Tags: assassins-creed-revelations

When I started playing Assassin's Creed Revelations and started looting some of the guards I killed, I found several items to make bombs with.

When you pick up new items you get a description of what effect the this item will give to a bomb.

**Does anyone have a complete list of all the different effects?**

Comment: proably if it's out for a few weeks i guess :s

Comment: I only just started, but it looks like there's a section in the in-game database that lists all the ingredients and their uses...

Comment: Doing the Piri Reis missions explains pretty much everything you'll need to know about bombs. They give you free bombs **and** are pretty fun too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [this crafting guide](http://www.gamefront.com/assassins-creed-revelations-bomb-crafting-guide/):

> **Bomb Effects**
>
> Caltrop – Caltrop Bomb (Tactical) – Slows and stuns enemies by
>   covering an area of ground with metal spikes. Perfect for stopping
>   pursuits and blocking narrow paths. Ezio is not damaged by caltrops.
>
> Lamb’s Blood – Blood Bomb (Tactical) – Sprays blood in an explosion,
>   causing fear and panic. They incapacitate, but for only a short amount
>   of time.
>
> Shrapnel – Splinter Bomb (Lethal) – Sprays shards of metal in
>   all directions, hurting or killing anyone caught in the blast. Like a
>   modern frag grenade, beware of killing civilians.
>
> Salt of Petra – Smoke Decoy (Diversion) – Releases a thick smoke that draws guards to
>   it. Useful for luring guards and breaking their line of sight. Less
>   noisy and more discreet than other diversions.
>
> Phosphorous – Smoke Screen (Tactical) – Blinds victims with a bright flash and creates
>   smoke that breaks line of sight. Enemies caught in the smoke are easy
>   to kill, and Ezio can see through the smoke with his eagle vision.
>
> Datura – Datura Bomb (Lethal) – Releases a cloud of poison smoke that
>   hurts and incapacities anyone caught by it. Beware of killing
>   civilians, the effect is similar to the Poison Dart.
>
> Coal Dust – Thunder Bomb (Lethal) – Creates a powerful explosion, it is less
>   powerful than other bombs, but will stun and disable anyone not killed
>   in the explosion.
>
> Skunk Oil – Stink Bomb (Diversion) – Drenches anyone
>   with a strong stink caught in the blast, very useful for separating
>   targets from crowds or other guards. Any guard caught in the stink
>   will stop until the effect has worn off.
>
> Sulfur – Cherry Bomb (Diversion) – Pops with a loud noise, and attracts guards from far > and wide to investigate the noise.
>
> Pyrite Coins – Gold Bomb (Diversion) –
>   Like throwing coin on steriods, the explosion will spray an area with
>   coins, any citizen will become hostile to guards coming to
>   investigate, creating a big instant crowd and diversion.
>
> **Bomb Casings**
>
> Fuse Shell – The default casing, it bounces off surfaces or NPCs and
>   explodes after three seconds. The extra time can be useful for
>   escaping and hiding before the bomb goes off.
>
> Impact Shell – Explodes on impact with an NPC or surface. If you need an immediate > explosion, use this casing. Best used for lethal bombs, where you’ll rarely need
>   to set a killer trap, or just need to defeat a large group quickly.
>
> Trip Wire – Explodes when enemies walk near, a perfect casing for
>   setting traps. Set these on guard patrol routes.
>
> Sticky Pouch – Sticky to any surface of NPC it lands on, then explodes after five seconds.
>   The delay helps Ezio escape, and being able to land a bomb on a
>   specific target means you always know at least one of your intended
>   targets will be caught in the blast.
>
> **Bomb Gunpowder**
>
> Indian Gunpowder – 2 meter blast radius. Best used for precision
>   attacks where you need to limit civilian casualties.
>
> Arabic Gunpowder – 3 meter blast radius. Medium, for when you need a slightly larger
>   effect on your targets.
>
> British Gunpowder – 4 meter blast radius. Best used for large groups, save these large blasts for tactical bombs that limit civilian death.